# Get informations from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a domain where users have a subdomain with its own name.

Example:

- User: Vitor
- Subdomain: vitor.google.com

The database has the column `user` table `my_users` and have the columns `birthday`, `address`, `password`, `city` and `state` in table `users_infos`.
How do I do that in PHP in `index.php` can get this information direct user to the database?

this is my incorrect code:

```
// Get Subdomain
$urlExplode = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
if (count($urlExplode) > 2 && $urlExplode[0] !== 'www') {
    $subdomain = $urlExplode[0];    
    echo $subdomain;
}


// Select DB
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users_infos i INNER JOIN my_users u on u.id = i.id where u.users='$users'"; 
    $result = mysql_query($sql); 
    if($result === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error());
     // TODO: better error handling 
    }

else {
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$userTitleSite = $row['userTitleSite'];
echo $id_textos = $row["id_textos"];
echo "<br />";
echo $id = $row["id"];
echo "<br />";
echo $phone = $row["phone"];
echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";

}

// Says that the subdomain is = user
$subdomain = $user;
```

Correct answer below:

Using the help you gave me, it looks like I got here ..
follows the correct code I could do for future users who have the same question:

```
// Get subdomain
$urlExplode = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
if (count($urlExplode) > 2 && $urlExplode[0] !== 'www') {
    $subdomain = $urlExplode[0];    
    echo $subdomain;
}


// Says that the subdomain is = user
$user = $subdomain;


// Select DB
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vms_textos i INNER JOIN vms_users u on u.id = i.id where u.user='$user'"; 
    $result = mysql_query($sql); 
    if($result === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error());
     // TODO: better error handling 
    }

else {
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$userTitleSite = $row['userTitleSite'];
echo "<br />";
echo $id_textos = $row["id_textos"];
echo "<br />";
echo $user= $row["user"];
echo "<br />";
echo $id = $row["id"];
echo "<br />";
echo $telefone = $row["telefone"];
echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";

}

echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";
```

Thanks all for help me! :)

Comment: Where is the variable used as a SQL parameter, $users, set?

Comment: @trf i forget do add in post, but still does not work

Answer (score 0):

```
$subdomain = $user;
```

Should go before the $sql, as your code is written $user is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the WHERE clause `u.id = i.id` is correct? In other words, do the ID columns in your my_users and users_infos table match? It is more common to have a foreign key reference on the users_infos table (e.g. my_users_id), in which case the query would be something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users_infos i 
INNER JOIN my_users u on u.id = i.my_users_id
WHERE u.users='$users'
```